# Git - Vendor folder modifications - .gitignore?

Tags: git, laravel, composer-php, gitignore, vendor

So I have a Laravel installation in which I have modified several Laravel core files in the vendor folder (mainly mail related).

I want everyone who clones the repo to have the same changes obviously. What is the correct way of handling this?

- Remove the vendor folder from the .gitignore completely and index it all?
- Keep the vendor folder in the .gitignore and add an exception for the specific files I have modified? (but this will then overwrite these files when a collaborator does composer install, right?)

Comment: Instead of overwriting the vendor files you can extend those files and override the functions in your project. This way the vendor files would be untouched and every one would have the same configuration which you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Fork Laravel repo: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/
2. Make a new branch in forked repo, branch name must be prefixed with `dev-`, e.g. `dev-bugfix`
3. Make changes in forked repo, commit them, push them to `dev-bugfix` branch.
4. Include forked repo in your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "version": "dev-bugfix",
            "name": "laravel/framework",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/<your_github_username>/framework.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "dev-bugfix"
            }
        }
    }],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "dev-bugfix"
    }
}
```

After this you can pull your custom changes anytime, without having to commit it to your specific project.

Read more about forking and loading packages here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

---

PS. it's a bad practice to modify vendor package files, try not to do that in future.

Comment: I followed your instructions (cloned Laravel-Framework repo, made changes, pushed to dev-bugfix branch, edited composer.json, removed vendor folder and used composer install) but sadly for some reason my changes don't appear. It's the default Laravel code that is installed.

Comment: Ah, I forgot composer update. Now it gives me the following error after cloning dev-bugfix: Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in /home/pepper/pepper/boots
  trap/autoload.php on line 46

Comment: @Basaa that's another error, you should create another question for it :)

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616294/composer-forked-laravel-4-2-not-installing