# Composer - Forked Laravel 4.2 not installing

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have cloned the Laravel 4.2 branch from Github and pushed it to a private GitLab server. I've created a new branch from 4.2 with the name dev-bugfix and added a comment in 1 file to see if composer would install my fork and not the official Laravel.

My steps:

- Cloned Laravel 4.2 branch from Github
- Pushed the repo to a private GitLab server
- In an existing Laravel application, removed composer.lock, ran composer dump-autoload and removed the entire vendor folder
- Edited composer.json to include my private repo:

  ```
  "repositories": [{
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
          "version": "dev-bugfix",
          "name": "laravel/framework",
          "source": {
              "url": "my-gitlab-repo",
              "type": "git",
              "reference": "dev-bugfix"
          }
      }
  }],
  "require": {
      "laravel/framework": "dev-bugfix",
      "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~1.8"
  },
  ```
- Ran composer install

Composer starts with cloning my fork of Laravel-framework after which it installs a few dependencies. Then, Artisan wants to clean compiled, where it fails. Complete output [click](http://pastebin.com/hdFNx2g6)

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [patchwork/utf8](https://packagist.org/packages/patchwork/utf8) package.

In the `require` section in your composer.json add: `"patchwork/utf8": "1.2.*"` and then do `composer update`.

Comment: But this package is already in the composer.json of the forked Laravel package? Composer should read the composer.json from my repo and automatically install it, right? It's part of Laravel!

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload` then, it help [sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21817902/1331425)